# Android. Размер apk

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

Доброго времени суток! У меня возник такой вопрос. Я написал приложение под android с помощью Xamarin. Затем собрал его в релизе, выполнил publish, получил подписанный apk. И ужаснулся, так как размер apk составляет аж 25 мегабайт. Приложение вполне тривиальное, ресурсов в нём немного (общий размер 3 мегабайта). Если оставить тоьлко одну архитектуру ameabi-v7a? то размер сокращается до 19 мегабайт. Затем я попробовал сделать линковку. По умолчанию было выбрано SDK assemblies only, я поменял на Sdk and user assemblies, затем снова сгенерировал apk. В этот раз его размер стал более приемлемым - 12 мегабайт (хотя и это чересчур) . Но после этого возник очень странный баг - почему-то из Listview (которое является главным элементом в основной активити) пропали все строки. Притом этот баг проявляется только в релизной сборке, в debug сборке всё в порядке.

Я хотел бы узнкать, какие есть способы уменьшения размера apk без побочных эффектов? Все-таки 25 мегабайт - это очень много

Comment: Писать на нативной для Android Java?

Comment: @pavlofff я не готов переписывать десятки тысяч строк кода. Наверняка есть способы получше

Comment: Но с другой стороны нельзя использовать "левый" фреймворк с другим языком и надеятся уложиться в пару мегабайт. Приблизить к размеру нативного приложения не получится даже близко. В любом случае, на меньше ~10Мб для приложения на xamarin расчитывать, думаю, не стоит

Comment: @pavlofff я и не говорю про пару мегабайт. Но 25 - это очень много

Comment: Все, что вы можете сделать, написано в ответе. Это позволит "ужать" на процентов 30, наверное. Такова цена

Comment: Вы как-то много хотите - и кроссплатформенное приложение, и чтобы бинарник был маленький. Так не бывает. Выберите что-то одно.

Answer (score 4):

Да вроде как там только сам Mono весит под 10 метров.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Единственное, что можно сделать - это использовать [linking](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/) и [ProGuard](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#ProGuard) включить (ну и там в статье ещё есть советы).

Можно ещё [распилить](http://motzcod.es/post/112072508362/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down) .apk в зависимости от архитектуры, чтоб он не паковал arm'ы с x86 в кучу.

Comment: я пробовал линкинг, но после этого появился странный баг, который мне не удалось локализовать. С proguard тоже были проблемы, но о них лучше в отдельном вопросе